# Turn URL encoded string into UTF-8

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, character-encoding

Yesterday I faced problem about getting some Unicode strings from URL. Actually I use CodeIgniter and the URL segments will be passed into controller/function(**parameters**). I don't know is it the CI changes the encoding or it's something else. I have the right encoding in my HTML page in the content and in the address bar till I get those Unicode segments.

For example:

```
localhost/df-gamez/news/افتتاح-جدید-سایت-تیم-دریم-فکتوری
```

The last segment is perisan characters which is under UTF-8. It's present correctly in everywhere but when I get it in my code It will turn to something like this:

```
%d8%a7%d9%81%d8%aa%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%ad-%d8%b3%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%aa-%d8%ac%d8%af%db%8c%d8%af-
%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85-%d8%af%d8%b1%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%81%da%a9%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b1%db%8c
```

I tried to change it to UTF-8 with `mb_encode` but it didn't. Both my HTML page and Controller file are formatted as UTF-8 Without BOM.

Peace Out!

Answer (score 9):

Use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function to decode.

```
echo urldecode("%d8%a7%d9%81%d8%aa%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%ad-%d8%b3%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%aa-%d8%ac%d8%af%db%8c%d8%af-%d8%aa%db%8c%d9%85-%d8%af%d8%b1%db%8c%d9%85-%d9%81%da%a9%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b1%db%8c");
```

will give you `افتتاح-سایت-جدید-تیم-دریم-فکتوری`

Comment: It gave me **������-����-����-���-����-������**

Comment: @MahanGM Do you add this `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` to your html head?

Comment: Yup. I said it first. It's correct in the page. Also I tried **iconv** as in **urldecode** page someone mentioned it.

Comment: It's truly amazing! I don't know why it's acting like this :). I think I found the problem. As controllers never contains any char-set define in the head Cuz it's usual! so I should add one. But CI documentation didn't say something about that!